# SBT by default installing 1.0.3 version over 0.13.6

Tags: scala, sbt, version

I am trying to install **SBT 0.13.6** version in my **ubuntu**. For this I do the following steps:

```
wget http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-0.13.6.deb
sudo dpkg -i sbt-0.13.6.deb 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

After installing, when I check the sbt version, it shows **version 1.0.3**.

Here is the command:

```
hadoop@localhost:~$ sbt about
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.0.3 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
    confs: [default]
    69 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (22027kB/913ms)
Getting Scala 2.12.4 (for sbt)...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (18986kB/225ms)
[info] Loading project definition from /home/hadoop/project
[info] Set current project to hadoop (in build file:/home/hadoop/)
[info] This is sbt 1.0.3
[info] The current project is {file:/home/hadoop/}hadoop 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.12.4
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, sbt.plugins.Giter8TemplatePlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.12.4
```

And my **Scala** version is not **2.12.4**; it's **2.11.8**. Why is it showing wrong versions?

```
hadoop@localhost:~$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.8 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL
```

Did I made any mistake?

Answer (score 13):

*SBT* - whichever version you have installed - will download a project-specific version of *SBT* when it runs. If no such version is specified, it will use the installed version. If you want a particular project to use *SBT* 0.13.6, then you create a file called `./project/build.properties` (relative to your project's root directory, which will be `/home/hadoop/project/build.properties` in this particular case) with the following content:

```
sbt.version=0.13.6
```

*SBT* will then download that version and will use it to build your project.

Consequently, I strongly recommend that you always install the latest version of *SBT* on your machine, since that will simplify matters going forward.

BTW, I notice that you used `dpkg` to install a specific *SBT* version, but you then used `apt-get install sbt` - which will likely install the latest *SBT* release (I'm guessing release 1.0.3) for your version of *Ubuntu*, replacing the version you installed via `dpkg`. What was the output from those commands? Alternatively, your `/home/hadoop/project/build.properties` file - if present -
may be specifying *SBT* version 1.0.3.

One other thing to consider: the `sbt` command should be executed from a project directory - a directory that contains just your project's sources. It's not a good idea to run `sbt` from your `HOME` folder, as it will leave some output folders behind (such as `./project`, `./target`, etc.)

When compiling *Scala* sources, *SBT* will use the version specified in your *SBT* build file (or the version used to build the *SBT* version being used if that property is undefined) - it does *not* use any installed versions of *Scala* that you may have on your machine.

If you want to use *Scala* 2.11.8, then add the following line to your *SBT* build file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

I strongly recommend that you review the [*SBT* documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/index.html) on its web-site.

Comment: Interesting but not always so apparent